# Securing Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, security

PHP makes it relatively easy to limit what a user can do on a server - just instruct it to disable features via the php.ini disable_functions directive.  Is there a similar capability in Node.js?  A spot of googling with the more obvious phrases has turned up a blank.  I imagine one can do something similar by controlling just what can go into the requires clauses.  However, perhaps there is another way?  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to point me in the right direction.

---

Judging from the comments I need to clarify this question

1. **Context** - I am setting up a service which allows users to run their own Node code in a Docker container.  Docker containers are fairly secure but - as Docker make clear - there is no cast iron guarantee that the container is a Sandbox with no risk of anything spilling out of it.
2. Within reason I want to allow users to use external modules whose use is declared in their code using the standard Node require('modulename') syntax

Now suppose I let this happen and the user sticks in

```
require('shelljs/global');
```

Boom... the user has the ability to run shell commands.  So how do I stop this from happening?  One way would be to play policeman and strictly control what external modules the user can rope in in this way.  The other - and hence my question - if there is a php.ini style way of simply blocking access to certain capabilties... .  From my understanding of how Node works (and it is as yet imperfect) this is not possible.  However, given that I am a relative newbie I thought I would ask here and see what those who understand Node better than I have to say.

Comment: Code is evaluated at runtime, any edits to the JavaScript files will not affect the currently running app until it is restarted.

Comment: Do you mean, You as a server admin want to limit what developers or applications on that server can do within a node.js application?

Comment: @Kevin B - see my rephrased question.  Briefly the answer to your comment: yes.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, and if it were, It would also limit 3rd party module functionality in unpredictable ways. I would focus on the specific things that can get by the sandbox rather than as a whole disabling capabilities.

Comment: @Kevin B - good point about how it risks limiting 3rd party modules.  Similar things can happen in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but you can control what you export from module exports. For instance:

```
var DB = require("db");

var userFromDB = DB.find("username");

modules.exports = {
    publicUser: userFromDB.publicData
}
```

We only made `userFromDB.publicData` public instead of the entire `userFromDB` object. No one from the public can access anything else.

Comment: I am undoing the downvote on your answer given that you answered before I had expanded the description of the problem in my question.  The original, though perhaps perfectly clear to a PHP programmer, may not have been so to the present audience.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent one angle of attack is to set global `node_modules` path folder in the shell to something different then the default before running node.js.

Then you'd maybe have some issues with apps that actually require global modules, but you could `npm link` them or similar.